# How to determine which cell in grid mouse pointer is over?

Tags: vb6, grid, tooltip, coordinates, mousemove

```
Private Sub Grid1_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

    If  ????????????  Then Grid1.ToolTipText = <contents of cell>

End Sub
```

How can I use the `X` and `Y` coordinates to determine which cell the mouse pointer is currently over?

The implementation of `Grid` I am using only has a `MouseMove` event and not a `MouseOver` event.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Grid1_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
  Dim intRow As Integer, intCol As Integer
  With Grid1
    For intRow = 0 To .Rows - 1
      If y > .RowPos(intRow) Then
        If y < .RowPos(intRow) + .RowHeight(intRow) Then
          For intCol = 0 To .Cols - 1
            If x > .ColPos(intCol) Then
              If x < .ColPos(intCol) + .ColWidth(intCol) Then
                .ToolTipText = .TextMatrix(intRow, intCol)
              End If
            End If
          Next intCol
        End If
      End If
    Next intRow
  End With 'Grid1
End Sub
```

Comment: kinda brute, but doing the job